# How to connect to AWS S3 using Dasein API?

Tags: amazon-s3

anybody has used Dasein API, in order to connect to AWS S3 ?

I am looking for an example of how to use the API but I cant find anything.

Comment: I found [this](http://www.dasein.org/api/dasein-cloud/) and it looks clear to me

Comment: I have also looked into it. Although it provides a very good API documentation it doesn`t provide a clear example of how configure the storage service.